# PHP preg_repalce Replace %var% with text

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace multiple variables in a text. 
I have For example this text:

```
This is an example text , my variables are:
%name%
%frontname%
%lastname%
%email%
```

No I want to replace each variable that is between the % % characters with {$variable}.

So my output looks like this:

```
This is an example text , my variables are:
{$name}
{$frontname}
{$lastname}
{$email}
```

The pattern I am trying to use is this :

```
$textResponder = preg_replace('#\%[^\%]+\%#', '{$$1}', $text);
```

But that is not working, as I get this as output: `{$} {$} {$}.` Does somebody know what the correct pattern would be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = "Hello, %test% World %another test%!";
echo preg_replace('#%(.*?)%#', '{\$$1}', $var);
```

[Test here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YLCWPb)

Comment: Why are you escaping the `%` characters?

Comment: updated the code without the escape, result doesn't change, just makes it a tiny bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace('/%(.*?)%/', '{\$$1}', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gert Van de Ven You need to escape the dollar's special meaning:

```
$var = "Hello, %test% World!";
echo preg_replace('#\%(.*?)\%#', '{\$$1}', $var);
```